# White pixel artifacts on borders when copying image using C# graphics

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, graphics, png

##### I have some PNG image which looks in Windows Photos like this (it has transparent background)

[image], scaled: [image]

##### When I import this in Unity it looks like that:

[image], scaled: [image]
As you can see there are already some artifacts on the border of image.

##### For my needs, I want to copy that image using C# Graphics class.

```
private void Copy(string inFile, string outFile)
{
    using var source = Image.FromFile(inFile);
    var output = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);

    using var ia = new ImageAttributes();
    using var g = Graphics.FromImage(output);

    g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
        0, 0, source.Width, source.Height,
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
    output.Save(outFile);
}
```

##### After copying, in Unity image looks like this:

[image], scaled [image]

Is it possible to fix that artifacts with C# Graphics classes?

I tried changing settings in both Graphis and ImageAttributes objects, like below, but that all doesn't help

```
// these are options I tried in various combinations
ia.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

P. S. my real use-case is simplifed to MRE

Comment: Is there any reason not to use unity3d embedded api for this? I mean this one https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.CopyTexture.html.

Comment: @Morion I think main reason that I use this code to import images in project while transforming them.. so using Unity API I should perform extra steps - add that to project source files, and remove them after transformations

Comment: I asked because you mentioned Unity3d in the related tags.

Answer (score 0):

Upon furter investigation, I found out that all I need was `g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;`. I know what I mentioned in question that I tried that and had no luck, but when I try it now it works like a charm.

So working code appears to be:

```
private void Copy(string inFile, string outFile)
{
    using var source = Image.FromFile(inFile);
    var output = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height);

    using var g = Graphics.FromImage(output);
    
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

    g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
        0, 0, source.Width, source.Height,
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    output.Save(outFile);
}
```